# How to use a subset of a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, pdf, pdfpages

I am trying to take the PDF output of a `beamer` presentation and take only a subset of the slides, and create a PDF file out of them (I can't recompile the `beamer` presentation with the relevant slides, since they are annotated).

When I use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1-15]{presentation.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The pages are enlarged, and the pdf slides are not the usual size of a `beamer` presentation slide.

If I change document class to `beamer`, all pages appear blank.

How can I fix that?

Comment: You can just use a tool to extract the pages you want or remove the ones you don't directly from the PDF. Preview in Mac OS X lets you do that. So does pdftk.

Answer (score 5):

If you know how big your presentation slides are do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=197mm,paperwidth=254mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
    \includepdf[pages=1-15]{presentation.pdf}
\end{document}
```

If you use `beamer` documentclass, you don't even have to know the size of the slides, just exchange the default white background with a transparent one to make the slides visible:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}

\begin{document}
    \includepdf[pages=1-15]{presentation.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

For testing purposes, said that the original presentation is `xxx.pdf` generated from:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Non Source Presentation}
\author{Someone}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Lore}  \begin{frame}{Lore ipsum}     \lipsum[1] \end{frame}
\section{Ipsum} \begin{frame}{Nam dui ligula} \lipsum[2] \end{frame}
\section{Dolor} \begin{frame}{Nulla malesada} \lipsum[3] \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Then, in your new presentation, to include only the slides 1 and 4 from `xxx.pdf`, you can simply insert each PDF page as images:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0pt,text margin right=0pt} 
\begin{document}
\frame{\includegraphics[page=1,width=\textwidth]{xxx.pdf}}
\frame{\includegraphics[page=4,width=\textwidth]{xxx.pdf}}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: MWE]